# Choose a valid template solution that can render custom functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid, mustache

I'm wondering how to let my customer 'personalize' their view executing some of my custom functions using an mustache/handlebar format, but I'm not able to understand how to do it effectively. I have it in my mind the flow, but in code, I don't know where to start.

Example given: 
I want my users to be able to invoke a function/method called `read_json(url,key)`

So in my mind, the flow should be to have a template like mustache or liquid and have: `Today the weather is {{read_json(https://weathersystem,temperature)}} degrees` and have it rendered to: Today the weather is 56 degrees.

Or maybe having a set of functions that the user will declare as variable   weather somewhere in my rails database, specific to the user like:  `weather=read_json("https:/weathersystem", temperature)` and then the user would be able to do something like: `Today the weather is {{weather}} degrees`

Since the text or function the user might want to add  or `{{ function }}` to be rendered every time it's invoked by the users since the text they have this could be rendered in a normal view or into an API response.

I'm kinda struggling figuring it out what or how can be done.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be done on client side

so if you use jQuery, you can do this

#### your view file: x.html

```
<div>Today the weather is <span class="read-json" data-type="weathersystem" data-subtype="temperature"></span> degrees</div>
```

#### javascript file

```
$('.read-json').each(function(el) {
   var $el = $(el)
   var type = $el.data('type')
   var subType = $el.data('subType')
   // url = ... set URL based on `type` and `subType` variable above 
   $el.load(url)
}
```

Comment: Hi Saiqul, thanks for taking the time answering, but  sadly, this could not match the need that I have. I want the function in mustache or {{ function }} to be rendered every time it's invoked by the users since the text they have this could be rendered into an api response.

Comment: 'read_json' is a javascript function, right? if it's a asynchronous request, then read this one to implement your own helper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666557/how-to-run-a-callback-when-mustache-js-has-finished-rendering-template